# CPU acceleration status: KVM is not installed on this machine (/dev/kvm is missing)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have worked in eclipse for android, but now i have shifted to android studio, After downloading android studio from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) :

1. setup sdk with studio
2. created android project
3. created an AVD  (cpu x86_64, android 5.0.1 Nexus one, api 21 )
   But when i tried to run avd, it is giving an error below
   [image]

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

need help, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Install kvm using apt-get or look to genymotion for emu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by enabling virtualization in BIOS, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564910/kvm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine-dev-kvm-is-missing) for more details, :)